# How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in java?

Tags: java, parsing, hex, long-integer

I want to convert a hex string to long in java.

I have tried with general conversion.

```
String s = "4d0d08ada45f9dde1e99cad9";
long l = Long.valueOf(s).longValue();
System.out.println(l);
String ls = Long.toString(l);
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4d0d08ada45f9dde1e99cad9"
```

Is there any way to convert String to long in java? Or am i trying which is not really possible!!

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add a "0x" prefix to the string before calling valueOf

Comment: Umm ... did you look in the javadocs?  Save yourself time and always look in the javadocs first.

Comment: Also, valueOf should accept a second parameter that specifies the base. Try passing 16 (and the string without the prefix)

Comment: @sinelaw - I think you are confusing `Long.valueOf(String)` with `Long.decode(String)`.  The Javadoc for `valueOf(String)` says *"Parses the string argument as a signed decimal long."*

Comment: Stephen, right, it's decode that accepts the prefix. But valueOf accepts the base parameter (see link above)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[`Long.decode(str)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a variety of formats:

> Accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal
>   numbers given by the following
>   grammar:
>   DecodableString:
>
> - Sign<sub>opt</sub> DecimalNumeral
> - Sign<sub>opt</sub> 0x HexDigits
> - Sign<sub>opt</sub> 0X HexDigits
> - Sign<sub>opt</sub> #  HexDigits
> - Sign<sub>opt</sub> 0  OctalDigits
>
> Sign:
>
> - -

But in your case that won't help, your String is beyond the scope of what long can hold. You need a [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
String s = "4d0d08ada45f9dde1e99cad9";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16);
System.out.println(bi);
```

**Output:**

> 23846102773961507302322850521

For Comparison, here's [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE):

> 9223372036854775807

Comment: Not sure about System.out.println method signature, but using bi in a String assignment I needed to use bi.toString()

Comment: @JECarterII println on an Object calls that object's toString() method

Comment: Crisp Clear Thanks!

Comment: By printing the stack trace, it seems that `Long.decode()` just calls `Long.parseLong()`.

Comment: @PLG it's a facade around `Long.valueOf`, which in turn uses `Long.parseLong`. The specific purpose of `Long.decode` is to detect whether the input string is decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, and then call `Long.valueOf` with the detected base.

Answer (score 47):

Use parseLong:

```
Long.parseLong(s, 16)
```

Comment: True in general, but fails in this case (the number is much too large for a Long)

Comment: still it throws NumberFormatException,it's too long.

Comment: @Suresh: Yes, your sample string cannot be converted to a long, I was just answering "How to convert a hexadecimal string to long". You may want to look at BigInteger as Sean Patrick Floyd mentioned.

Comment: The goal is to convert to a Long, right? Then this is the clean and easy way to do it!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd That's the OP's problem, not this answer's.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd If the string cannot be converted to a Long, it should fail and throw an exception. It's the developer's job to handle that exception.

Answer (score 15):

```
new BigInteger(string, 16).longValue()
```

For any value of someLong:

```
new BigInteger(Long.toHexString(someLong), 16).longValue() == someLong
```

In other words, this will return the `long` you sent into `Long.toHexString()` for any `long` value, including negative numbers.  It will also accept strings that are bigger than a `long` and silently return the lower 64 bits of the string as a `long`.  You can just check the string length <= 16 (after trimming whitespace) if you need to be sure the input fits in a `long`.

Answer (score 10):

`Long.parseLong(s, 16)` will only work up to `"7fffffffffffffff"`. Use `BigInteger` instead:

```
public static boolean isHex(String hex) {
    try {
        new BigInteger(hex, 16);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what no-one is saying. Technically, you should be able to parse a unsigned long with a string with lenght 16 and only F's (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF), but Long.parseLong() only works up to 7fffffffffffffff, like you said.