# Parsing integer strings in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer, radix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153811/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-long-in-java)

I know that Java can't handle this:

```
Integer.parseInt("0x64")
```

Instead you have to do this:

```
Integer.parseInt("64", 16)
```

Is there something built into Java that can automatically parse integer strings for me using the standard prefixes for hex, octal, and lack of prefix for decimal (so that I don't have to strip off the prefix and explicitly set the base)?

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`Integer.decode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Integer.decode("0x64");
```

The decoding rules are as follows:

```
Prefix  Type
        DecimalNumeral
0x      HexDigits
0X      HexDigits
#       HexDigits
0       OctalDigits
```

Note: `decode` is available in [`Short`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29), [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29), and [`Long`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I knew there was something. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's [Long.decode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Did you read the details?: _is there something built into Java that can automatically parse integer strings_

Comment: @noob Wanna pick nits, eh? Okay. The question said "integer" not "Integer" and Java Longs are integers.

Comment: Once again, did you _read the details_? No reason to get all pissy.

Comment: @noob Of course I read it. Calm down.