# In Java, I want to take a string representing a hex and convert it to an int while preserving the "0x" prefix

Tags: java, hex, int

See how int a and int b have the prefix "0x" before the hex value? I want to make more of these from a string. I tried to use parseInt from Integer, but I get a NumberFormatException. Can anyone help?

```
int a = 0xA;
int b = 0x4;
String f = "0xF";    
int d = Integer.parseInt(f, 16);
```

I want "int d = 0xF"

Comment: Does it really matter that much?  As far as I know, you'd have to manually strip it off anyway, it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: Do you want to output as a Hex string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
String f = "0xF";    
int d = Integer.parseInt(f.substring(2), 16);
System.out.println(d);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
15
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Integer.decode("0x64");
```

A similar question was asked before in SO, here's a link for more info:

[Parsing integer strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599534/parsing-integer-strings-in-java)