# Hexa String to Int java

Tags: java, hex

I have:

```
int number = 0x00000024;
```

And it have no problems,
but now im get it from with de format:

```
<MAN>
      <NAME hexa="0x00000001"/>
</MAN>
```

And I try to parse hexa with:

```
Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(0), 16)
```

But it says:

```
Unable to parse '0x00000001' as integer
```

Anyone knows whats happening?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153811/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-long-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `0x`:

```
Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(0).substring(2), 16)
```

Comment: Actually, the answer in @DRCB's link is even better Integer.decode: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer in [How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153811/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-long-in-java), you want:

```
int num = Long.decode(parser.getAttributeValue(0)).intValue();
```

Comment: CHeck the first answer, I'll prefer that

Comment: @Daniel I prefer this method mainly because it decodes other formats correctly. Also it doesn't create an additional intermediate string object.