# Convert hexadecimal number to long integer

Tags: java, decimal, hex

I am trying to convert an hexadecimal number into a decimal number, but it doesn't work for very large values (over 2,147,483,647 in decimal),because int type is limited there.

Here is my code which works for integers

```
String nombreHexa = h2d.getText().toString();
            if (isHex(nombreHexa) == true) {
                int deciInt = Integer.parseInt(nombreHexa, 16);
                String newDeci = String.valueOf(deciInt);
                resulth2d.setText(newDeci);
            }
```

I tried to make deciInt a `long` but it wasn't so simple. The problem seems to come from the parseInt function (parseLong doesn't exist as well)

Does some one know how I should do it?

Comment: What range of values do you need to support?

Comment: I don't already know, but I think that an Int isn't enough. Sorry about the imprecision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whta's wrong with `Long.parseLong(String num, int radix)`?

```
String nombreHexa = h2d.getText().toString();
        if (isHex(nombreHexa) == true) {
            long deciLong = Long.parseLong(nombreHexa, 16);
            String newDeci = String.valueOf(deciLong);
            resulth2d.setText(newDeci);
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what was the problem when I tried it, maybe I forgot something. But with your code, it works. Thanks!
Edit : My bad, I just figured out what was wrong : I used Long.Long(nombreHexa, 16); (without the parse)

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153956/51197), use [`Long.decode(str)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

> Decodes a String into a Long. Accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal
>   numbers.

If you need larger than [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), [you should probably use BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153956/51197).

Comment: I tried walenborn's code and it works, but this way works too, and it allows BigInteger (which I didn't know)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[parseLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) exists as well. As long as it is only a size problem, you can use it.