# Convert hex string into long 17digits java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert `"0x6042607b1ba01d8dl"`  into a long.

I have tried:

```
long value = new BigInteger("0x6042607b1ba01d8dl", 16).longValue();
long value = new BigInteger("0x6042607b1ba01d8dl", 32).longValue();
long value = Long.decode("0x6042607b1ba01d8dl");
Long.parseLong("0x6042607b1ba01d8dl");
```

Note: The Hex number "0x6042607b1ba01d8dl" has 17 numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153811/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-long-in-java)

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you told us what happened as well, not just what you tried.

Comment: "The Hex number ... has 17 numbers."  Unless I'm mistaken, `6042 607b 1ba0 1d8d` has **16** digits so should fit in a 64b Java `long`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for the `BigInteger(String,int)` constructor:

> The String representation consists of an optional minus or plus sign followed by a sequence of one or more digits in the specified radix.

So you just need to remove the `0x` from your string:

```
long value = new BigInteger("6042607b1ba01d8d", 16).longValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [BigInteger constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) does not understand your 0x prefix.

Use e.g.

```
long value = new BigInteger("6042607b1ba01d8d", 16).longValue();
```

Or:

```
String number = "0x6042607b1ba01d8d";
long value = new BigInteger(number.subString(2), 16).longValue();
```

You can also use [Long.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29), which does accept a 0x prefix for decoding hex.

Comment: OP did use `Long.decode("0x6042607b1ba01d8d");` I'm not sure about the outcome tho

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
long value = Long.parseLong("6042607b1ba01d8d", 16);
```

Long.parseLong can sometimes fail for unsigned longs, so, the BigInteger approaches are better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Answers with some explanation are preferable.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that Long.parseLong can fail for unsigned longs, so, the BigInteger approches are better.

Answer (score 0):

As said by the above answers in code form:

```
String bigHexNumber = "0x6042607b1ba01d8d";
if(bigHexNumber.subString(0, 1).equals("0x") {
     bigHexNumber = bigHexNumber.subString(2);
}
long hexInLongForm = new BigInteger(bigHexNumber, 16).longValue();
```