# NumberFormatException while converting Hexadecimal String to Long

Tags: java, exception, validatelongrange

I am trying to convert the following Hexadecimal string `cc10000000008401` to Long.     Java unexpectedly generating `NumberFormatException`.

> System.out.println(Long.parseLong("cc10000000008401",16));

I think, It should not generate exception as the long representation of the above hexadecimal string is "-3742491290344848383L" which is well inside the range of Long.

Could you please help me to know why I am getting `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153811/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-long-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java8, `Long.parseUnsignedLong` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html?is-external=true#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-)) will handle this.

```
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("cc10000000008401",16));
```

produces

-3742491290344848383

Answer (score 4):

`cc10000000008401` is 14,704,252,783,364,703,233 which is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Since it overflows `long` you need to use `BigInteger` to store it. Since your text values comes as hex you can parse it [providing correct radix:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int))

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("cc10000000008401", 16);
System.out.println(i); // 14704252783364703233
```

Comment: Could you please tell how did you calculate its decimal value. I am getting following decimal value: ‭-3742491290344848383‬

Comment: I mean, How did you get this value "14,704,252,783,364,703,233".

Comment: as he commented/answered, by `new BigInteger("...", 16)`  (Note that `parseLong` expects a `-` sign for negative numbers)